# Updating ListView - receiving SMS - Android

Tags: android, listview

I wrote an application which receives messages and adds them to the ListView (I'm a total beginner, experience level 0)... When I launch an app and I'm in MainActivity and I receive a message, it is written to the list, but the problem is that when I'm on activity called 'SmsActivity', while receiveing sms, the list doesn't update/refresh. (I need to back to MainActivity, switch again to SmsActivity and only then I see new meessages.)

```
public class SmsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView list_view;
public static ArrayList<String> lista_sms = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);

    list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    // adding do list in ReceiverSMS.java
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista_sms);
    list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I have receiving messages declared in other class:

`public class ReceiverSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            str += "" + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SmsActivity.lista_sms.add(str);
        SmsActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}`

Does anybody know how to update list without switching back to MainActivity and again to SmsActivity?

Answer (score -1):

I see your using static methods to update your view , if possible try using observer pattern. else try this

```
myListView.invalidateViews();
```

Example for observer pattern based broad cast receiver.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
            Observer {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            BroadcastObserver bco = new BroadcastObserver();
            bco.addObserver(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void update() {
            //TODO: call your desired function
        }
    }
```

BroadcastObserver.java

```
public class BroadcastObserver extends Observable {
    private void triggerObservers() {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void change() {
        triggerObservers();
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    BroadcastObserver bco = new BroadcastObserver();
    bco.change();
}
```